# Pandas - Group into 24-hour blocks, but not midnight-to-midnight

Tags: pandas, time-series, dataframe, grouping

I have a time Series. I'd like to group into into blocks of 24-hour blocks, from 8am to 7:59am the next day. I know how to group by date, but I've tried and failed to handle this 8-hour offset using TimeGroupers and DateOffsets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) with parameter `base`:

```
print df
                 date  name
0 2015-06-13 00:21:25     1
1 2015-06-14 01:00:25     2
2 2015-06-14 02:54:48     3
3 2015-06-15 14:38:15     2
4 2015-06-15 15:29:28     1

print df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='24h', base=8)).sum()
                     name
date                     
2015-06-12 08:00:00   1.0
2015-06-13 08:00:00   5.0
2015-06-14 08:00:00   NaN
2015-06-15 08:00:00   3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively to @jezrael's method you can use your custom grouper function:

```
start_ts = '2016-01-01 07:59:59'
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(start_ts, freq='10min', periods=1000)})

def my_grouper(df, idx):
    return df.ix[idx, 'Date'].date() if df.ix[idx, 'Date'].hour >= 8 else df.ix[idx, 'Date'].date() - pd.Timedelta('1day')

df.groupby(lambda x: my_grouper(df, x)).size()
```

Test:

```
In [468]: df.head()
Out[468]:
                 Date
0 2016-01-01 07:59:59
1 2016-01-01 08:09:59
2 2016-01-01 08:19:59
3 2016-01-01 08:29:59
4 2016-01-01 08:39:59

In [469]: df.tail()
Out[469]:
                   Date
995 2016-01-08 05:49:59
996 2016-01-08 05:59:59
997 2016-01-08 06:09:59
998 2016-01-08 06:19:59
999 2016-01-08 06:29:59

In [470]: df.groupby(lambda x: my_grouper(df, x)).size()
Out[470]:
2015-12-31      1
2016-01-01    144
2016-01-02    144
2016-01-03    144
2016-01-04    144
2016-01-05    144
2016-01-06    144
2016-01-07    135
dtype: int64
```